# Nested if else-if throwing "unexpected error" in R

Tags: r, if-statement, error-handling, nested-loops

I am trying to select the column `sn_r` from the data set `va` where `va$VACHART==`. If this condition is satisfied then I want to store the value in a new column while calculating it using the formula `5+50*log10(va$sn_r)` If the condition does not satisfy it, then search in a different range value of `sn_r` and store it.

In R, I have tried using the if, else if statements but there is an unexpected '}' error in "}"

```
if(va$VACHART=="1" & va$sn_r>"0.025"){
va$ETDRS_R = 85+50*log10(va$sn_r)
}else if(va$VACHART=="1" & "0.020"< vd$sn_r <="0.025"){
va$ETDRS_R = 5
}else if(va$VACHART=="1" & "0.015"< vd$sn_r <="0.020"){
va$ETDRS_R = 3
}else if(va$VACHART=="1" & "0.005"< vd$sn_r <="0.015"){
va$ETDRS_R = 1
}else {#if(va$VACHART=="1" & "0"< vd$sn_r <="0.005"){
va$ETDRS_R = 0
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the data in a reproducible format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several of the conditions inside the `if` are not valid syntax, e.g.

```
"0.020" < vd$sn_r <= "0.025"
```

This would have to be expressed as:

```
vd$sn_r > "0.020" & vd$sn_r <= "0.025"
```

That being said, it isn't even clear to me that these columns aren't in fact numeric.  In any case, we *could* try to correct your code, but a better approach would be something like `case_when` from the `dplyr` package:

```
va$ETDRS_R <- case_when(
    va$VACHART == 1 & va$sn_r > 0.025 ~ 85+50*log10(va$sn_r),
    va$VACHART == 1 & va$sn_r > 0.020 ~ 5,
    va$VACHART == 1 & va$sn_r > 0.015 ~ 3,
    va$VACHART == 1 & va$sn_r > 0.005 ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim this seems much easier and works well :)